# I am updating my nuget packages and they are not updating and keep giving error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, nuget-package, nullreferenceexception

When I am updating my nuget packages, I get an error. Help me with this error.

Error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.
>
> at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c.b__9_0(PackageIdentity package)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.  d__9.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
> at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.  <b__0>d.MoveNext()

I have tried:

1. Delete Bin and Obj file
2. Build and Rebuild
3. Clear All Nuggets Cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not alone here, there is an active issue on the NuGet GitHub, link below:

[Updating in PMUI causes Object reference not set to an instance of an object #9882](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9882)

User Ian1971 was able to solve the issue by updating the packages one by one:

> Same issue here. I can only get it to work by doing each update one at a time.
> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
> Version 16.7.5